# How do I get the line number and path of a method from a pdb using .Net?

Tags: .net, debug-symbols, pdb-files, dia-sdk

Given an assembly and its pdb, how do I get the line number and path to a method using .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [DIA SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6tay6cz.aspx).  Microsoft does not have a managed interface for it, but [using DIA in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697541/how-do-i-use-the-ms-dia-sdk-from-c) has been asked on StackOverflow before.

If you are going to try it out in native first you can get the information in question by getting the `IDiaSymbol` instance for the PDB in question, this is called the ['global scope'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkcc8hx6.aspx).  Once you have that you will call [`findChildren()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfx1573w.aspx) passing it the `SymTagFunction` enumeration which of type [`SymTagEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkedss5f.aspx).  You will then need to enumerate over them and use an `IDiaSession`, previously made to get the global `IDiaSymbol`, instance to find the correct source and line number.